# Ellipse representing horizontal and vertical error bars with R

Tags: r, plot, drawellipse

In R, how to use ellipses to represent error bars (standard deviation) for x and y variables if only summary data, i.e. mean and SD for different data sets, are available. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function like this one:

```
draw_ellipse = function (mean_x, mean_y, sd_x, sd_y)
{
    ellipse <- function (x) { sin(acos(x)) }
    t = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 100)
    el_y = sd_y*ellipse(t)
    newx = mean_x + sd_x * t
    polygon(c(newx, rev(newx)), c(mean_y + el_y, rev(mean_y - el_y)), col = "grey", border = NA)
}
```

You can use it very easily using `apply()`:

```
x = runif(10)
y = runif(10)
sd_x = abs(rnorm(10, 0.1, 0.02))
sd_y = abs(rnorm(10, 0.05, 0.01))
plot(x, y)
df = data.frame(x, y, sd_x, sd_y)
apply(df, 1, function (x) { draw_ellipse(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]) })
points(x, y, pch = 3)
```

**Solution for plotting ellipses with different colors:**

```
draw_ellipse = function (mean_x, mean_y, sd_x, sd_y, colidx)
{
    ellipse <- function (x) { sin(acos(x)) }
    t = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 100)
    el_y = sd_y*ellipse(t)
    newx = mean_x + sd_x * t
    polygon(c(newx, rev(newx)), c(mean_y + el_y, rev(mean_y - el_y)), col = as.character(colors[colidx]), border = NA)
}

x = runif(10)
y = runif(10)
sd_x = abs(rnorm(10, 0.1, 0.02))
sd_y = abs(rnorm(10, 0.05, 0.01))
plot(x, y)
colors = rainbow(length(x))
df = data.frame(x, y, sd_x, sd_y, colidx = 1:length(x))
apply(df, 1, function (x) { draw_ellipse(x[1], x[2], x[3], x["sd_y"], x["colidx"]) })
points(x, y, pch = 3)
```

Comment: Tomas, thanks for your quick response. Great. I applied the code to my data, which worked fine. However, data ellipses are partially overlapping. As data represented different resources, is it possible to use a different colour coding for the ellipses? Ta very much. This is how my data looks like...
x <- c(0.42, 1.25, 0.02, 0.47, 3.78, -0.0288, 0.41, 6.33, -0.2888)
y <- c(3.3, 4.7, 1.6, 3.4, 6.7, 2.6, 3.8, 5.9, 0.2)
sd_x <- c(0.16, 0.25, 0.02, 0.32, 1.35, 0.0264, 0.18, 3.78, 0.64)
sd_y <- c(0.4, 0.5, 2.6, 1.9, 1.55, 2.9, 1, 2, 0.2)
plot(x, y, xlim=c(-2,12), ylim=c(-2,9))

Comment: @peanut, welcome, it's great that it helped. You have two possibilities - either try to remove the `border = NA` which will print you border around each ellipse, or try to change the col argument to change along some pallete (see `?palette`). You would then need to add additional argument `col` to the `draw_ellipse` function and supply it in the `apply` call.

Comment: Tomas, one last question. I go with the the boarder now, but would like to stay with coloured ellipses. How to a supply a "col" argument to they "apply" call?

Comment: @peanut, just add a new column to data frame, e.g. `df = data.frame(x, y, sd_x, sd_y, col = 1:length(x))`, and then use it in the apply call. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might like the function `car::ellipse`   , i.e., the ellipse() function in the car package.

Answer (score 0):

The `ellipse` function in the `ellipse` package will take summary information (including correlation) and provide the ellipse representing the confidence region.